Clear Power Query Cache (in Excel via VBA) before Refreshing the query
I've been seeking an answer to this question for some time... and have not found a solution. Any help you can suggest is appreciated. I'm using a Windows machine. I've drawing a table or records after processing an entire folder of xlsx files and it works great... most of the time.
THE PROBLEM:
An anomaly happens infrequently with my Power Query output results, in Excel, where the collated records it draws in from a folder of XLSX files are showing records from a previous period; the same period but duplicates, or just piles the same records on top of the previous refresh. I need to catch this before it happens and causes any more problems. It only occurs once a month but that is already too much. I need to eradicate this issue. The only way I can get around it is if I change the parameters and process a previous periods records which previously was perfect. Running that perfect output somehow brings it back into working order again.
I'VE READ:
Someone suggesting to use ID#s for each record, use Table.Distinct and/or use the 'Remove Duplicates' command as a step in PQ. I have not tried any of these as I mentioned it's sometimes showing an old refresh which is very weird and I believe the problem is elsewhere.
WHAT I NEED:
What i'd like to do is, in this Sub in my Class Module:  Private Sub pQueryTable_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
or in this sub in my Module:   Public Sub Refresh_All_Queries_With_Status_Updates(ws As Worksheet)
I'd like to run a 'clear cache' line of code.
I have not been able to find how to do that yet. I can do it by opening the query and doing it through the options (there was only 5MB in there to clear, not very much...).
Does anyone have any idea how I can instruct Power Query to clear it's cache before refreshing in either of those two locations above?
Thanks in advance.
VBAS.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].
Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Hi, I can't issue the code and supporting source files as it's confidential information in the source files. I've indicated the places where the one line of code should go. At the moment there's no errors as I mentioned it happens randomly and there is NO error while it happens so I can't attached any error message. in the section 'THE PROBLEM:' there is a detailed account of what kind of problem i'm experiencing.
